# torch train with gpu correct always same

Tags: torch

I am new in torch,i have installed `torch7` on `Ubuntu14.04` with `cuda8.0` and `cudnn5.1`. I have tried `mnist` and `cifar10` with CPU and it's good.The code i use, `train-on-digit-classifier` and `train-on-cifar`, are on [GitHub](https://github.com/torch/demos).
I have add below code before training with GPU.

```
cutorch.setDevice(1)
model = model:cuda()
criterion = criterion:cuda()
trainData.data = trainData.data:cuda()
trainData.labels = trainData.labels:cuda()
testData.data = testData.data:cuda()
testData.labels = testData.labels:cuda()
```

It can run but the correct always the same in every epoch.
Can someone tell me where is wrong?